# Can't get json content from remote url

Tags: php, json, file-get-contents

I've tried everything but still can't get JSON content from following url: http://onderbrekingen.infrax.be/onderbrekingen/Home/GetOnderbrekingen

This is my lastest php:

```
$url = 'http://onderbrekingen.infrax.be/onderbrekingen/Home/GetOnderbrekingen';
$curlSession = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://onderbrekingen.infrax.be/onderbrekingen/Home/GetOnderbrekingen');
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curlSession, $jsonData = json_decode(curl_exec($curlSession));
curl_close($curlSession);

switch (json_last_error()) {
case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
    echo 'json_decode() - Maximum stack depth exceeded';
break;
case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH:
    echo 'json_decode() - Underflow or the modes mismatch';
break;
case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
    echo 'json_decode() - Unexpected control character found';
break;
case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
    echo 'json_decode() - Syntax error, malformed JSON';
break;
case JSON_ERROR_UTF8:
    echo 'json_decode() - Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded';
break;
default:
    echo 'json_decode() - Unknown error';
break;
case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
    print '<b>JSON var_dump:</b>';
    print '</br></br>';
    var_dump($jsonData);
    print '</br></br><hr></br>';
break;
}

print '<b>echo content:</b>';
print '</br>';
echo stream_get_contents(fopen($url, "r"));
```

I've also tried it with `file_get_contents()`, also doesn't work.
`var_dump` returns `NULL` everytime.
`stream_get_contents` also doesn't seem to return the raw JSON content.

Grtz,
phyck

Comment: Telling us the output rather than just "it doesn't work" would be pretty helpful

Comment: Why : curl_setopt($curlSession, $jsonData = json_decode(curl_exec($curlSession));

Comment: Just write: $jsonData = json_decode(curl_exec($curlSession));

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
curl_setopt($curlSession, $jsonData = json_decode(curl_exec($curlSession));
```

with

```
$jsonData = json_decode(curl_exec($curlSession));
curl_setopt($curlSession, $jsonData,true);
```

It worked just fine when i tested it

```
//output
{"Onderbrekingen":[{"Id":"5f303a78-6bcb-e711-80d7-005056b663fa","Cabinenummer":"097LTF","Onderbrekingstype":"Storing","Discipline":"Elektriciteit","Postcode":" ","Gemeente":" ","BeginDatum":"\/Date(1510873200000)\/","EindDatum":null,"BeginUur":"08:46","EindUur":null,"Latitude":0,"Longitude":0,"GeimpacteerdeStraten":[],"GeimpacteerdKlantAantal":"101 - 500","ExtraBeschrijving":null,"DnbCode":null,"Scada":true,"InterneOpmerking":"Aangemaakt vanuit SCADA","IsRedLine":true,"ValidationErrors":null,"IsValid":true,"IsDirty":true,"Error":""}],"ScadaSync":"19:16"}<b>JSON var_dump:</b></br></br>int(1)
```

---